# Textbox Binding to a double property returns Error Message when entering not a number value in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, textbox

I have a TextBox binding to a double property. Here is the xaml

```
 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Margin="0,0,0,15" 
          Name="textBox_algorthWheight" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <TextBox.Text>
         <Binding Path="AlgorithmWeight" StringFormat="N1">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
               <ExceptionValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
          </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>
```

The property Code as shown below

```
 public double AlgorithmWeight
    {
        get { return _algorithmWeight; }
        set
        {

                if (value < 1.0)
                {
                    value = 1.0;
                }
                _algorithmWeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlgorithmWeight");
        }
    }
```

MVVM WPF will take care of the exception when I do enter a non number value it will highlight the textbox in red colour which is good but I really want to add an error message next to the text box to notify the user the value is not acceptable, and I will use the previous value or a default value. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should implement IDataErrorInfo.  See here for a tutorial, this will show you how to create the message and style your textbox when an error is present:
[Link](https://tarundotnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-in-wpf/)